# 6 string guitar, low B?

Tags: guitar

Following on from a question around 4 yrs ago, with sparse response: has anyone actually done what I propose - changing the strings to low B (with an F♯ for the new 2nd)?

I was successful with adapting a 4 string bass to BEAD, several years ago, which was straightforward, but this just may be more problematic. What issues am I likely to find, before I venture forth? Obviously the gauges will be changed appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

[Yes, it's been done many times*.](https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/en/wiki/B_tuning)  Conceptually, a guitar is just a small, high pitched bass, or vice-versa, so you need to make the same considerations as an EADG-BEAD change, and could encounter the same issues.  Buy a 7-string set (BEADGBE) and use the bottom 6, or buy one of the heavy 6-string sets now available with similar gauges.

If you have a 25.5" scale 6-string, the instrument will perform similarly to a 25.5" scale 7-string.  You will almost certainly have to modify the nut to fit the new thicker strings.  You will need to setup the guitar again- intonation, relief, action- but that's no different than if you just installed a different weight of strings.

The only major issue you might encounter is bottoming out the intonation range of adjustment.  Look at the bridge saddles (especially for the low E string)- do you have room to go lower?  If yes, you should be fine- if no, you may need to make some modifications to the bridge.

One last minor consideration- I am firmly in the "Wound G" camp- and you have a slightly lower F# string here.  If you love your plain G, then a plain F# is fine, but if you are on the fence or prefer a wound G, get a wound F#.

*I have not verified the accuracy of this list.

Comment: I tend to use plain 3rds, .012" as it happens, so since that becomes the 2nd, .014 would seem about right. Maybe even go plain D, at around .018?

Comment: 0.18 would be very loose as a D.  And even the lightest set in the Ernie ball slinky line doesn't use a plain D, they use 22w.  I'd recommend using the same D string as you would on your EADGBe guitar as a starting point.  (D string = the one that's tuned to D, not the 4th lowest).  If you want a more bendable third, get a lighter string (22w-24w at the lightest) but not a plain third.

Comment: If that list is to be believed, I'm in wonder. Also wonder which mainstream bands have resorted to baritone tuning. Duane Eddy, I think.